# Why is the limit $\lim_{x \to c}{(1+x)^{(1/x)}} = e$ only when $c=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I am wondering if the limit
$$
\lim_{x \to c}{(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}}
$$
can be $e$ when $c \neq 0$.

I have tried the following:

1. When $c$ is $\pm \infty$, the limit is $1$, not $e$.
2. When $c \in (-1,0)\cup(0,\infty)$, the function $(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$ is continuous, and the limit itself equals to $(1+c)^{\frac{1}{c}}$. We can find that the function is decreasing at such a domain, so the value can never be $e$.

But I don't know what to do when $c \in (-\infty,-1)$. One more thing, I haven't learnt anything about complex analysis, so I want the codomain of the function $(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$ be $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order that you can work within the real line you have to assume that $1+x >0$ or $x >-1$.

$e^{x} >1+x$ for all $x \neq 0$. Hence we cannot have $(1+c)^{1/c}=e$ or $e^{c}=1+c$ with $-1<c<0$.

Note: $e^{-t} >1-t$ for $t >0$. This follows from the fact that $e^{-t} -(1-t)$ is an increasing function on $[0,\infty)$ and its value at $0$ is  $0$.

Comment: The problem is, a real function $(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$ is not defined at some point when $x<-1$, so it may not be continuous everywhere.

Comment: @Captain_HeGuan Answer edited.

Comment: But the function is defined at some points when $x<-1$ (e.g. $x=-3$). I want to know if there exists a $c<-1$ such that the limit is $e$.

Comment: @Captain_HeGuan It does not holds for such points. Hint: take absolute values.